# Keyboard shortcut in Excel to jump to next visible region/area

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

On an Excel spreadsheet, the visible columns based on my typical screen resolution range from A to O (15 columns). Assume that the cell pointer is in `A1`.

Is there a shortcut to move the cell pointer to `P1` and change the visible columns from P to AD (15 columns)? Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> takes me to the rightmost column (ZZ or something far).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>PageDwn</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd>